# Replace characters in *.csv files

Tags: csv

I have a folder with 6 csv files. All the files have the same structure and one cell data is shown like this:

G/T

I want to replace all the "/" for ":" so I used the command:

```
sed "s|/|:|" File1.cs  > File1_done.csv
```

This works but the problem is that in some cases, the same cell contains this data:

./.

And in this cases i want to keep the "/".

Thanks!

Comment: What tool/language are you using to do this? I haven't used notepad++ in a while, but if it has regex replace functionality, you could probably ignore ./. fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to replace the ./. first with something else (say ###) then do the / replace. then finally swap the ### back to ./.

Comment: OP would just have to be careful that the ### (or whatever) does not exist elsewhere in the document. Otherwise they'll end up with some unexpected ./. replacements.

Comment: Tryed but when i do: sed "s|./.|###|" File1.cs  > File1_done.csv it replaces all the G/T and other data with "/" also